# Runtime exec bat cmd to remove drive connection

Tags: jsp, batch-file, runtime

cmd.bat

```
net use Z: /d /y
```

test.jsp

```
<%

    String log = "";
    Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p = null;
    String cmd = "C:/cmd.bat";
    try{
        p = r.exec(cmd);
        p.waitFor();
    }catch(IOException ie){
        ie.printStackTrace();
        log = ie.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        log = e.toString();
    }

%>

exception:<%=log%>
```

There is no exception in my case. However this code didn't exec cmd.bat correctly. My Z: disk exists still. So I try another way

```
p = r.exec("net use Z: /d /y");
```

but got "nothing" again. Any problem ?

Comment: Are you trying to read the command from the `.bat` file before you try to run it through java

Comment: I didn't read. but I can exec("dos command string"). Can't I ?

Answer (score 0):

This should help you ,

`String cmd = "cmd /c start Z:\\cmd.bat";`

It is working i have tested it with a *PING* command , I guess something is wrong with your drive or the file that is to be executed is present in the same drive and it may be the reason you cant disconnect it.

Comment: have you checked the location of `cmd.bat` file ?

Comment: Move your file another location and try it out